# Python Django Method Syntax Error

Tags: syntax, python-3.6

Trying to work my way through a Django tutorial, and can't seem to get past this syntax error when I implement a new method:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)


    def__str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
```

Whenever I run it, I get a syntax error at 
    def_str_(self):

I've checked all of the indents to make sure the spaces are consistent, and I've tried the same method using only spaces and only tabs and neither work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space between `def` (a keyword) and `__str__` which is the name of the method you are **def**ining.